# Select within Select

Tags: mysql, sql

Iam trying to do an exercise that it has to do with select within select.I have in where error syntax I don't know why.The exercise it asks me  '

> Which country has a population that is more than Canada but less than
>   Poland? Show the name and the population.'

I did this

```
SELECT name FROM world
  WHERE population >
     (SELECT population FROM world
      WHERE name='Canada')
  WHERE population < 
     (SELECT population FROM world
     WHERE name='Poland')
```

Comment: Only 1 where  allowed and research AND and OR

Comment: Replace `WHERE population <...` with `AND population <...`

Comment: Does the question specifically require a SELECT within a SELECT?

Comment: it says me too few columns..

Comment: The question says 'Show the name and the population' you are only showing name..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following, replace your second `where` with `and`.

```
SELECT name FROM world
  WHERE population >
     (SELECT population FROM world
      WHERE name='Canada')
  and population < 
     (SELECT population FROM world
     WHERE name='Poland')
```

Comment: it says me too few columns

Comment: i find it near of name I should have had population

Comment: @maikl Yes! :) glad you figure it out. Please accept the answer by clicking on the tick mark. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use between.

```
SELECT name FROM world
  WHERE population BETWEEN
     (SELECT population FROM world
      WHERE name='Canada')
  and 
     (SELECT population FROM world
     WHERE name='Poland')
```